# How to make constant part of page using Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm making website using (and learning) Symfony2. In my code, I always have to make 2 queries and display their results in sidebar, just like that:

```
Groups (251)

PHP
JS
Java
C++
...

Users (1542)

user1
user2
userN
...
```

How to make it using Twig & Symfony2? I ask about where to place it. I thought about requesting it in template, but I don't know how to do it. Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Embedding controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) seems like the best fit.